# Need help understand this relay function in go-shadowsocks2

Tags: go, network-programming

```
// relay copies between left and right bidirectionally. Returns number of
// bytes copied from right to left, from left to right, and any error occurred.
func relay(left, right net.Conn) (int64, int64, error) {
        type res struct {
                N   int64
                Err error
        }
        ch := make(chan res)

        go func() {
                n, err := io.Copy(right, left)
                right.SetDeadline(time.Now()) // wake up the other goroutine blocking on right
                left.SetDeadline(time.Now())  // wake up the other goroutine blocking on left
                ch <- res{n, err}
        }()

        n, err := io.Copy(left, right)
        right.SetDeadline(time.Now()) // wake up the other goroutine blocking on right
        left.SetDeadline(time.Now())  // wake up the other goroutine blocking on left
        rs := <-ch

        if err == nil {
                err = rs.Err
        }
        return n, rs.N, err
}
```

This is from the go-shadowsocks2 project, however, I couldn't understand the left.SetDeadline(time.Now()) part, and what does the comment (wake up the other goroutine blocking on left) mean?

SetDeadline with argument of time.Now() seems unusual, can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 2):

This might help, from the net.Conn documentation:

> A deadline is an absolute time after which I/O operations
> fail instead of blocking. The deadline applies to all future
> and pending I/O, not just the immediately following call to
> Read or Write. After a deadline has been exceeded, the
> connection can be refreshed by setting a deadline in the future.

It appears like there are two goroutines copying data from one connection to the other. When the source connection for either of those operation close, that copy operation will terminate, but the other copy operation will be blocked. Based on the net.Conn documentation, by setting the timeout it will cause the blocked copy operation to fail, unblocking the gouroutine.

Comment: According to the doc of net.Conn, `// Close closes the connection.
    // Any blocked Read or Write operations will be unblocked and return errors.
    Close() error`, so when the source connection for `io.Copy()` closes, the other copy operation will be unblocked, not be blocked as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: There are two copy operations, `copy(a,b)` and `copy(b,a)`. If `a` is closed, the `copy` reading from `a` will stop, but the copy reading from `b` will still wait to read from `b`. The timeout is used to unblock that.